# GMAIL API: Get Label ID by Label Name

Tags: gmail-api

How do you get the Label ID by Label Name?

I can get the Label ID by getting the list of Labels and parsing the response. But that looks a pretty inefficient way of doing it when I'm only interested in a particular label.

Is it possible to get Label ID directly be passing the Label Name?

Answer (score 4):

No, you cannot. However, listing your labels is one of the least expensive API calls you can do, so no worries!

Answer (score 1):

I created this function for just that purpose, hope it helps:

```
function getLabelIdByName(labelName) {
  var me = Session.getEffectiveUser().getEmail();
  var labels = Gmail.Users.Labels.list(me, {q: ""});
  for (var l=labels['labels'].length-1; l>=0; l--) {  
    if (labels['labels'][l]['name'] === labelName) {
      return labels['labels'][l]['id'];
    }
  }
}
```

NOTE: For this function to run correctly you must enable the Advanced "Gmail Service" in your script (pretty easy), learn more here:  https://developers.google.com/apps-script/advanced/gmail